# How can I disable the Extension Gallery when making a custom VS Code build?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to disable the online extension gallery cause I don't want developers to download any extension that could be potentially dangerous. Is there any simple setting that allow it?

Options:

- I could use the --no-proxy-server option to avoid access to the extension gallery. However some extensions require it.
- I could use a read-only extension folder and the --extensions-dir option. However some extensions need write permissions on that folder.
- I found out that there is a a key called "extensionsGallery" in resources\app\product.json I think I could remove those URLs:

```
        "nlsBaseUrl": "https://www.vscode-unpkg.net/_lp/",
        "serviceUrl": "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery",
        "cacheUrl": "https://vscode.blob.core.windows.net/gallery/index",
        "itemUrl": "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items",
        "publisherUrl": "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/publishers",
        "resourceUrlTemplate": "https://{publisher}.vscode-unpkg.net/{publisher}/{name}/{version}/{path}",
        "controlUrl": "https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/extensions/marketplace.json",
        "recommendationsUrl": "https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/extensions/workspaceRecommendations.json.gz"
```

but I'm **not sure if I break something important. Is it safe to remove those URLs?**

**Is there a setting I can just set to avoid installing extensiones freely?** I want to build a custom flavored VS Code with some extensions but not allowing users to do everything.

Comment: you can always download the vsix file and install it by just unzipping the vsix file and copy it to the extension directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to build a custom flavored VS Code with some extensions but not allowing users to do everything.

Then make a product.json that does that. See also [this comment from @chrisdias (a member of the VS Code team)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60#issuecomment-161792005).

> I found out that there is a a key called "extensionsGallery" in resources\app\product.json I think I could remove those URLs, but I'm not sure if I break something important. Is it safe to remove those URLs?

[The default/template product.json](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/product.json) doesn't even have those properties defined, and if you look at VS Code's type definition of `IproductConfiguration` in [src/vs/base/common/product.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/base/common/product.ts),  you'll see that the `extensionsGallery` property is nullable. If the type definition says the `extensionsGallery` property can be left out, I think that means it's fine to leave out. The Extensions View will not have any backing service, but users will still be able to install extensions by downloading VSIXes and installing them with `code --install-extension`.

Comment: Thanks starball. I can disable extensionsGallery section if it safe.  Users could still be able to install extensions by downlading VSIXes. I suppose that if I use a extension folder with read-only permissions they won't be able to do that but maybe it is not a good practice and some extension could fail.

Comment: A user could launch VS Code with a modified --extensions-dir where he has rights too... I think it maybe make no sense try to harden a develop environment.